# R package check in RStudio - function not found error

Tags: r

I am trying to build a package in R using RStudio / git.

When I run the check function on this file:

```
#' A function to print variable names for easy pasting to a new character vector.
#'
#' @param x a data.frame
#' @examples require(convPkg5);cat_names(iris)
#'

cat_names <- function(x){
  cat(paste(",'", names(x), "'", "\n", sep = ""))
}
```

I get this error message:

```
checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in ‘convPkg5-Ex.R’ failed
The error most likely occurred in:

> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
> ### Name: cat_names
> ### Title: A function to print variable names for easy pasting to a new
> ###   character vector.
> ### Aliases: cat_names
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> require(convPkg5);cat_names(iris)
Error in cat_names(iris) : could not find function "cat_names"
Execution halted
```

All of the other files / functions have a similar structure but are not generating error messages.  What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe need to export the function for it to be accessible in examples?

Comment: As @joran hinted, look at your `NAMESPACE`.  Maybe this function is not exported and you need `:::` to access it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you ever got this figured out, but I was having the same problem and found the solution for my issue in Hadley's [R Packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#exports)

You should be able to fix the problem by adding `@export` do your roxygen comments as below

```
#' A function to print variable names for easy pasting to a new character vector.
#'
#' @param x a data.frame
#' @examples require(convPkg5);cat_names(iris)
#'
#' @export
```